# Copy from `OS X` and paste using `OS X Screen Sharing` to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: macos, copy-paste, screen-sharing

I have a Raspberry Pi which I access from my Mac using `ssh` and `VNC` (`tightvncserver`).
I am using `OS X Screen Sharing`

I want to be able to copy from `OS X` and paste into a GUI app on the Pi.
(Copying using `ssh` works as normal).

`Share the contents of the Clipboard with another Mac` mentions using `Edit >Use Shared Clipboard`, but this option is greyed out when sharing the Pi.

Is there any way to paste into the Pi GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answer did not work, but is no longer an issue.

I use the RealVNC server now included in Raspberry Pi OS and installed the [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) which allows Copy/Paste.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try would be installing `autocutsel` on the Pi.

You can find details at [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/tightvnc-copy-paste-between-local-os-and-raspberry-pi).

Once you have that installed try both turning on shared clipboard and sending the clipboard from the Mac.

If that doesn't work then try a VNC client app such as [Chicken](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/).

Comment: I tried this, and rebooted the Pi (but not the Mac), and unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

When working on python scripts my work-around is to open a terminal session on the mac and SSH in to the Pi at the same time as the screen sharing session. I do the copy pasting in the terminal session (running nano editor) and everything else in the screen sharing session. Not an elegant solution.